# ansible date time filter to display data and time as "May 11, 10:36 PM"

Tags: datetime, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have the ansible_date_time fact collected in my operator but would like to display it as "Month Day, time" for example "May 10th 10:36 PM" in Eastern Time on one of my statusDescriptor fields. How do we achieve that using ansible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User 2700022 is very close but it is not "ansible-y" to shell out to an external process when ansible provides the [`strftime` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) (and besides, the `lookup("pipe"...` version would want to provide the formatting characters in order to produce the output format you requested)

Thus:

```yaml
- debug:
   msg: '{{ "%b %d %I:%M %p" | strftime }}'
   # May 11 10:11 PM
```

Comment: Thank you, any way to perform timezone conversion from UTC to EST in ansible just for this debug task (and not at the playbook level) ? The default value coming out is in UTC for the above statement.

Comment: It actually seems [it already uses `localtime`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.8/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L113), so you may have to run it as a `local_action:` or `delegate_to: localhost`, assuming your control node is in EST and your servers are in UTC. Barring that, I would guess some wizardry with `ansible_date_time.tz_offset` would be required, but try the first trick before we get all TZ math crazy

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise `lookup` plugin for this.

```
tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ lookup('pipe','date') }}"
```

Since `pipe` returns output from the command given, you can structure any possible formats available for `date` command. For possible formats supported in date, run `man date`